# jQuery DataTables event preXhr.dt doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I need to include some data to to ajax request before request send. I set up event handler `preXhr.dt` but it doesn't fire by some reason

```
$('.js-paging').on('preXhr.dt', function(e, settings, data){
    console.log(settings, data)
})
```

So no log data, event haven't fired.

HTML

```
<span class="previous paginate_button">
    <a class="link js-paging" href="#">Previous</a>
</span>
```

Comment: You should attach this event to datatable element.

Comment: @py3r3str ok, did $('.transactions_table').dataTable().on('preXhr',... not work either

Comment: Shouldn't be event attached before creating datatable?

Comment: @py3r3str can you please bring an example

Comment: example is there: https://datatables.net/reference/event/preXhr

Comment: @py3r3str I did like there, but that code doesn't work, so I posted  question here

Comment: No more ideas on this. But there is another way to add data to the request . You can manipulate the data object in option `ajax.data`, like one example from https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All events in dataTables is triggered directly on the `<table>` element itself (look for `_fnCallbackFire` in the source => `$(settings.nTable).trigger( e, args )`), thus you cannot catch the event on an arbitrary `<a>` element as you do above.

```js
$('table').on('preXhr.dt', function(e, settings, data){
```

```js
$('#<table-id>').on('preXhr.dt', function(e, settings, data){
```

```js
$('.<table-class>').on('preXhr.dt', function(e, settings, data){
```

works.